# Concerning the homological mirror symmetry conjecture

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

The generalized homological mirror symmetry conjecture states that for mirror dual models $(X_E, w)$ and $(X_E', w')$ , if $L$, a lattice polytope which is a Newton polytope of a nonsingular projective toric variety,  is in $M_{R}$ , then isomorphisms exist between:
$D^b(X_E,w)$ and $DFS(X_E',w')$, $D^b(X_E',w')$ and $DFS(X_E,w)$, where $DFS$ is the derived Fukaya category and $D^b$ is derived category of coherent sheaves. 
What cases of this conjecture are open?
Any references are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture has been solved for elliptic curves, abelian varieties, non-singular torus bundles over affine manifolds, and quartic surfaces. It remains to find a unification from algebraic geometry. A few references for this subject are the following:

Kontsevich, Maxim (1994), Homological algebra of mirror symmetry, arXiv:alg-geom/9411018.
Kontsevich, Maxim; Soibelman, Yan (2000), Homological Mirror Symmetry and torus fibrations, arXiv:math.SG/0011041.
Seidel, Paul (2003), Homological mirror symmetry for the quartic surface, arXiv:math.SG/0310414.
Hausel, Tamas; Thaddeus, Michael (2002), Mirror symmetry, Langlands duality, and the Hitchin system, arXiv:math.DG/0205236

Comment: Why not put this information in the original question?

Answer (score 3):

First - note that the way you state HMS in the setting you ask about (toric) is not exactly the way it actually is (because - in the "A to B direction" - you actually need to consider [the singular derived category](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302304.pdf) - see below).

Also you state your question as a general question about mirror symmetry  - while actually (if understood correctly) eventually ask specifically about mirror symmetry for toric manifolds.

Pay attention that (compact) toric manifolds are not Calabi-Yau - Hence it is not exactly [the setting HMS was originally defined by Kontsevich in 1994](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9411018) - that's no problem - because Kontsevich latter extended HMS to a more general setting (Lectures at ENS Paris, 1998) relating to ideas on [Landau-Ginzburg theory of sigma models due to Hori-Vafa](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0002222.pdf).

In relation to your question toric manifolds really turn to be a fantastic class of manifolds to study HMS (98). First - you need to make clear what is $X'$ - i.e the mirror in the toric setting. This is especially straight forward to describe for the subclass of toric Fano manifolds due to a [beautiful geometric construction due to Batyrev involving the notion of reflexive polytopes](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9310003). (From now on let's assume we are talking about toric Fano manifolds). In the HMS setting (a) the mirror is actually taken to be the open algebraic torus $(\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n$ in Batyrev's $X'$ (note that this is a non-compact manifold and that in general it's compactification $X'$ is a singular manifold) (b) it is also associated with a Laurent polynomial (or a generalization of such) $ W: (\mathbb{C}^{\ast}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ called the Landau-Ginzburg mirror potential which is the same as taking a hyperplane section of $X'$.

Now you have to introduce the categories you are working on. Let's start with the B-side on X goes to A-side on mirror $((\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n, W)$ case. Here the B-side is clear - you should practically look at $\mathcal{D}^b(X)$ (or some natural extension of it - to meet the $A_{\infty}$ structure on the other side). While on the A-side on the mirror you need to take into account what you are looking at as the Fukaya category of $((\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n,W)$. A famous and remarkable construction is the [Fukays-Seidel category](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Fukaya_Categories_and_Picard_Lefschetz_T.html?id=NOQxS9Tp50UC&redir_esc=y) which strongly uses Picard-Lefschetz theory. One of the features of the Fukaya-Seidel category is that it comes together with natural exceptional collections - determined by a collection of vanishing thimbles. One of the ways to prove HMS (98) (an approach which works for a much wider class of manifolds than toric) is to find the appropriate analog of the A-exceptional collection of thimbles in the B-side - that is, the derived category $D^b(X)$ - as once you have such an equivalence - you actually get a HMS-functor. One of the first applications of this approach (aside from original  applications due to Seidel for $X=\mathbb{P}^2$, for instance) is the work of [Auroux-Katzarakov-Orlov on toric Del-Pezzo surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506166) which established such a functor in this setting.

Specifically in the toric case, one also has a [remarkable approach due to Abouzaid involving tropical geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610004) - which works for any toric (Fano) manifold. (Abouzaid's approach to the Fukaya category on $((\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n,W)$ is slightly different, at least in the level of the definition, from the Fukaya-Seidel setting). Abouzaid notes that in the toric case $D^b(X)$ is generated (as a triangulated category) by $Pic(X)$ and identifies the mirror analogs of $Pix(X)$ in $((\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n,W)$ (W here is a slight modification of a Laurent polynomial) using an ingenious construction involving tropical geometry. This in particular, gives a HMS-functor, which is practically a proof of HMS in this setting.

The other case of A-side on $X$ goes to B-side on $((\mathbb{C}^{\ast})^n, W)$ - this is, traditionally, a bit slower to follow in terms of development than the B to A side. One of the features (mentioned in the beginning) is that as $X'$ is singular \ W is an algebraic fibration with singular fibers - you actually need to consider the singular derived category $D^b_{sing}(X')$ and not just $D^b(X')$ this adds some interesting features (relation to matrix factorizations) - and there are various open questions.